# Android Studio / Git / VCS Shelve

Tags: git, android-studio

I use Git for version control and Android Studio nicely integrates with it, love it!

But now, I did 'VCS->Shelve changes...'

and POOF, they were gone. I thought I needed to use stash, but then I thought let's see how to get it back, but I do not find a way to get it back.

Did anyone have this same issue and seem to resolve it?

Comment: Upvoted for "and POOF", no better way to explain, end of story.

Comment: seeing these kind of questions of past me when I get an upvote is like getting notifications from Google Photos about pictures I took x years ago :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find your shelf in the Changes window, which you can find under View -> Tool Windows -> Changes (or press ⌘9 on Mac, maybe Ctrl9 on Windows?)

Right clicking on your change gets you options for it, more info can be found at IntelliJ's doc site (since Android Studio is IntelliJ with some more Android stuff): http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea-tool-windows.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found it there. Have to investigate what the diff is between this an stashing. BTW: using Ubuntu here ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 4.1.1, I went to Tools->Local History->Show History. Also visible when I right click the project in the tool window.

Comment: This is incorrect, because this it eh local history, not the shelf